# re-export lodash exports in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using lodash in my typescript project with typings for lodash.
Besides I have some private npm module with utils I'm using in different projects.
It exports methods like that:

```
export * from './src/stringStuff';
export * from './src/httpStuff';
```

Want I want to do is providing lodash with that utils repo. So it would look like that:

```
import {
    forEach
} from '@foo/utils'
```

where `forEach`is a lodash method.
My approach was to add a lodash export like that in my index utils file:

```
export * from 'utils';
export * from './src/stringStuff';
export * from './src/httpStuff';
```

Now I can import and use for example `forEach` like in the example above.
BUT the thing is that the type script compiler gives me an error that `/files/@foo/utils/index.ts` has no exportet member `forEach`:

```
ERROR in [default] /files/@foo/utils/index.ts:1:14 
Module '"lodash"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.

ERROR in [default] /files/@foo/utils/index.ts:24:4 
Module '"/files/@foo/utils/index.ts"' has no exported member 'forEach'.
```

For me it's weird that I can use `forEach` but also get that error message. Why is that and how can I fix it? Is it a wrong import/export or maybe the typing file is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that text about different library structures:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html

And it seems to me like it's better to define lodash as a module like in that example file because I guess it's more like a UMD module?!
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Or here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-umd-module-definitions

Solved my problem to redefine lodash with my own typings file but I don't know if there's another solution...